# Can I say "Togo war deutsch"?

Tags: grammar, style

Can I say "Togo war deutsch bis 1918" ?

> Togo war eine der deutschen Kolonien in Afrika von 1884 bis 1918. Togo war deutsch nach dem Untergang Deutschlands in 1918. Nach der Unterzeichnung versailler Vertrag wurde Togo von Deutschland unabhängig u. an Frankreich übergeben.

Could one also write "Togo wurde deutsch bis 1918"? Would it change the meaning of the sentence entirely?

Comment: Your text presently reads: Togo was a German colony from 1884 till 1918. (ok) Togo was German AFTER the downfall of Germany in 1918. (???) After the treaty of Versailles was signed it became DEPENDENT on Germany and was given to France. (??????) So.. is this really what you wanted to say??

Comment: A version that makes more sense to me: Togo war deutsch bis zur Niederlage Deutschlands im Jahre 1918. Nach der Unterzeichnung des Versailler Vertrags wurde Togo von Deutschland unabhängig und an Frankreich übergeben. (Didn't check if that is what really happened)

Comment: Can't i write "Untergang"??

Comment: Hm... I know there's this movie "Der Untergang", but it wasn't the Untergang of Germany, because Germany is still on the map, but rather the Untergang of the Nazi-Regime.

Comment: The mental picture for "Untergang" comes from "untergehen" which in it's literal sense means that something sinks under the surface of some body of water. So a ship can "go under", and after it has done so, you can't see it any more on the sea.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33... as fifaltra mentioned "Untergang" implies that something is gone after. You could say "Untergang des Deutschen Kaiserreichs" because that was indeed gone after the war. There was no ceasar anymore.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33, please tell me, where do you get all these half-baked sentences with almost, but not quite, correct sentence structure or grammar? You seem to have an aptitude of finding German sentences that are missing a few bits to be correct, or in most cases are really, really not German as a German would speak. Where do you find these? If it's in a book, why don't you just trash the book?!!

Comment: i would like no d date for stat deutsch 2 in togo

Comment: "In 1918" sowieso nicht. Einfach "Togo war deutsch nach dem Untergang Deutschlands 1918".  "Nach der Unterzeichnung des Versailler Vertrags ..." - Versailler Vetrag ist ein Eigenname, ein fester Begriff, daher groß. Genitiv S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About Togo war deutsch bis 1918 vs. Togo wurde deutsch bis 1918:

You can say "Togo war deutsch bis 1918" if you want to say that it somehow belonged to Germany, but it might be considered sloppy and I wouldn't necessarily write it in an essay.

Now "Togo wurde deutsch bis 1918": That just doesn't make any sense. *werden* means *to become*, which is something that happens at some specific point in time. The "bis 1918" implies that it was a state that Togo was in for some time. You might say "Togo wurde 1884 deutsch" meaning that it became a colony in that year.

So, yes, it does change the meaning entirely, as might be expected when replacing *to be* with *to become*.

Comment: The "wurde deutsch bis" does make sense, you even explain it correctly: If it was a process that took a long time. I agree with the sentence not being what @DerPolyglott33 intended though.

Comment: Wurde deutsch is correct german than 'war deutsch' ?

Comment: @Oregon I thought for some time and couldn't come up with a sentence "Subj. wurde Adj. bis Zeitpunkt", so I think it is not really idiomatic. Especially here, where "becoming German" is something that probably happens by signing a treaty. But also for other stuff, you would probably rather say: "Er wurde immer verbitterter bis zu seinem Tod" and not "Er wurde verbittert bis zu seinem Tod". The *immer* marks a continual process in that case.

Comment: @DerPolyglott the degree of sloppyness is the same and additionally it doesn't really make much sense here.

Comment: You're saying "Untergang" doesn't fit in this context?

Answer (score 0):

> Togo war bis 1918 deutsch.

or

> Von 1884 bis 1918 war Togo eine deutsche Kolonie in Afrika. Nach dem Untergang des Deutschen Reichs, im Jahre 1918, wurde Togo (nach Unterzeichnung der versailler Vertrags) an Frankreich übergeben.

Comment: Welcome to German Language! Please note you are answering a very old and already answered question. Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which have already been answered many times before. Here is a guide on [How to Answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @help-info.de: the whole point of German Language SE is to build up a base of interesting questions with good community provided answers. In contrast to a forum this content will be valuable and available for a very long time, and to many other people. Therefore writing answers to old questions, editing out-dated content, or improving old to very old content is welcome here, if not vital.

Comment: @Tackat: Agreed. I see now - from another point of view it is different (German Language SE vs. Stack Overflow). My comment was quoted from the Help Center link above for a new user. I just checked it out and as aspected I found the same content for German Language SE and Stack Overflow. Different contents in the Help Center will probably not be enforceable.I will try to avoid such comments from now on for German Language SE.

Comment: I just didn't saw the creation date. And I have to agree with @Takkat. But thank you for the information!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. Both are valid.

> a) Togo war deutsch bis 1918.

Togo was German (owned, a colony…) until 1918.

> b) Togo wurde deutsch bis 1918.

Togo was German until 1918.

What is the difference?

Minimal or subtle. Depending on goal and context. They can be used as perfectly synonymous. Or with very slight differences:

Synonyms substituable for case a): remained, used to be, stayed, lasted, had been

Synonyms substituable for case a): became, remained, had been, grew, had become, stayed

Getting sticklish about this:

case a) says "Togo /to be/ German until 1918."
case b) says "Togo /to become/ German until 1918."

Historically Togo *was* a German colony. It *became* a colony before 1918, and it *was* one until 1918. Or did it only *become* a more perfect German colony until 1918?

Saying "Togo wurde deutsch bis 1918" is emphasising the end date *and* the process that lasted until that date. Colonisation isn't a one-time, one-date affair.
This says something like "Togo wurde deutsch, und blieb es, bis 1918" or "Togo wurde deutsch, und immer deutscher, bis 1918". *Wurde* thus captures a certain dynamic described, while *war* just states a legalistic fact: Until 1918, that was its legal status, it *was* so and so.

Ahistorical, but: "Togo wurde deutsch bis 1918" is a perfectly valid sentence that could express not the legal 'change-of-ownership' 1884 but the slow process (*not* 'precise' point in time) of the character of the land/the people there becoming more German, German-like. But being so sticklish over contradicting "doesn't make *any* sense" wird doch sehr deutsch?
It *can* make sense and probably does make sense if we look at the example cited:

> Togo war deutsch nach dem Untergang Deutschlands in 1918.

"Untergang" aside, that means Togo retained a lot of German features, structures perhaps mentality. The inhabitants, the locale elites, the remaining colonists, the civil servants kept some traditions, some language influences etc. Togo remained (a bit/a lot) German (features) after it was no longer an official German colony.

So stylistically and historically better fitting, I'd say

> Togo war/blieb sogar noch etwas 'deutsch' nach dem Deutschland 1918 seine Kolonien wie den Weltkrieg verlor…

Comment: "Togo wurde deutsch bis 1918" bedeutet, dass der Prozess des Deutschwerdens bis 1918 gedauert hat - erst dann war Togo deutsch. Eine Larve wird bis zum Juli (keine Ahnung ob das stimmt) ein Schmetterling, dann ist sie ein Schmetterling. Für Togo war aber mit dem Deutschsein 1918 Schluss. "Togo wurde Deutsch und blieb es bis 1918" wäre sprachlich richtig.

Comment: Humbug. Das ist sowas von quatschige Analogiebildung mit eingebautem Biologismus. Eine historische wie soziologische Bewertung erspare ich mir mal. Aber Deutschwerden ist deiner Logik zufolge also dem Satz nach von 84–18 nur zu einem Punkt als gültig anzusehen? Ich rede aber vom Prozess der in dem Satz abgebildet werden kann. Die Deutsch-SWler waren rechtlich 1918 über nächtens so ganz anders, dass sie ab 1919 Weihnachten nicht mehr mit Christbaum feierten, ferner alle weg, plötzlich muttersprachlos? "Eine Larve wurde eine Schmetterling bis X" schiessegel ob fertig, *dauerte* bis dahin.

Comment: Schwer zu folgen, Deiner Schimpftirade. Biologismus! Immerhin ersparst Du uns eine soziologische Bewertung - das weiß ich zu schätzen. Nein, meine Logik impliziert mit Nichten, dass der Prozess auf einen Punkt zusammenschrumpft. Allerdings kann es juristiscih durchaus Stichpunkte gegeben haben und muss es wohl auch, wenn geklärt werden muss, ob ein Vorgang nach dem Recht des dt. Reichs beurteilt wird oder nach vormals oder später gültigem Recht. Dass in 60 Jahren Deutsch schon zur Muttersprache in Togo geworden ist bezweifle ich einerseits, andererseits gebe ich zu bedenken, …

Comment: Der entscheidende Unterschied. Ob Larve und Imago oder Kolonie hier Protektorat da, das sind Zäsurierungen, die man machen kann. Aber in dieser, in keiner Variante hochsprachlich und historisch angemessen formulierten Aussage, (ohne weiteren Kontext) ist eben keineswegs exklusiv völkerjuristisch zu deuten. "Das ist *so* deutsch" ist auch keine juristisch gemeinte Aussage? Die Eisenbahn in Togo war 'so deutsch' nach 1919 wie vor 1913, auch wenn dann später primär Franzosen die Verspätungen organisierten?

Comment: … dass es Muttersprache für viele Österreicher und einige Schweizer, manche Italiener usw. ist, ohne dass diese deswegen Deutsche sind. Der Christbaum ist weniger signifikant für 's Deutschsein, von deutschen Juden und Atheisten angefangen bis zu all den anderen Nichtdeutschen Nationen, die mit Tannenbaum feiern, etwa Frankreich, welches Togo nach 1916 übernahm.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht wie Du jetzt auf deutsche Eisenbahn kommst. Was hat die Eisenbahn damit zu tun?

Comment: [Togo](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Sprache_in_Togo) is'n beknacktes Beispiel für das zu illustrierende Prinzip, historisch, IRL. In Namibia passt es besser. Es existieren Menschen die die(se) Eisenbahn so bezeichnen. Oder Österreicher. Aber etwas als 'ist deutsch' zu bezeichnen ist eben nicht beschränkt auf unbedingte Kongruenz zu Stempel in Pässen. Seh auch nicht wie diese Art von Insistenz auf für den Zweck abwegige, legalistisch-sophistische Spitzfindigkeiten die Kommentare hier bereichern. Ich mach Deskription und Analyse, mein Kritiker Proskription und Strafgericht.

Comment: Da es um klar umrissene Zahlen geht, 1884-1918, wird es sich wohl um eine völkerrechtliche Aussage handeln und nicht um eine der Essgewohnheiten, Weihnachtssitten oder Verkehrsmittel. Togo wurde vielleicht 1884 deutsch und blieb es bis 1918 (oder '16)  oder auch nicht, darüber kann man ja streiten, aber nicht, dass es bis 1918 (oder 1916) deutsch wurde. "Peter wurde Arzt bis 2012" mag heißen, dass er so lange Medizin studiert hat, womöglich umfasst es noch die Zeit als AIP - das muss kein Zeitpunkt sein, aber dann ist er Arzt und bleibt es. Er wird nicht immer weiter Arzt bis zur Pension.